# storing date time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I used to store dates in MySQL using TIMESTAMP value (int 15), but after reading this:

> http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

I'm confused somehow! It's really important for me to be able to show the dates for users in **different time zones**, and all dates are before year 2038.

Whats the best way for storing date times into MySQL db while we want to manipulate the dates in different time zones?

*(**please** first read the above article before sending any suggestions)*

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: You want us to read a veeeery long article before answering, and yet you can't be bothered to use google to find the answer to your question? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @JanHančič I already DID, that's where the above link is coming from :-)

Comment: There appears to be a good discussion and suggestions for your dilemma in the comments on that article. You can find your answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is suggested: Convert the dates to UTC first before storing them in the database as timestamp. Then, whenever you need to display them, just convert them on-the-fly to a user's timezone (with/without DST).

Comment: Mostly good practice, however it's sometimes impractical to capture the user's timezone (e.g. Europe/London) but it's usually trivial to capture the user's time zone ofset (e.g. +0100 Hours). It all depends on the OP wants to capture/display te data.

Answer (score -1):

Store them in BIGINT as timestamp converted to UTC+0 timezone.

Comment: Converting to a different data type does not intrinsically resolve the timezone issue and is bad practice - using UNIX_TIMESTAMPs have a limited range compared with DATE/DATETIME types and just stripping the formatting out of and ISO date undermines any attempt to manipulate / interpret the data in SQL

Comment: @symcbean, bigint, not type UNIX_TIMESTAMP, read carefully. And it's a pretty good practice.

Comment: Using an invented encoding system when the DBMS natively supports a semantically correct one is NEVER good practice - you didn't say *how* you convert it into a BIGINT - read my comment again.

Comment: @symcbean unix timestamp is already an integer value, no need to convert.